# rounding individual corners with php/imagick

Tags: php, imagick

is it possible to round individual corners with the imagick extension?

imagick::roundedCorners() seems to only do all 4 corners

Comment: Why not just do it with CSS (unless most of your users are using MSIE 6 or earlier)?

Comment: i assume the OP is rounding corners *within* an image, rather than rounding the corners of the image itsself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps take a copy of each corner before applying `roundedCorners`, then overlay each corner that you don't want rounding back over the original.